# How to rotate plot tick labels

Tags: ticks, rotation

I am trying to plot a set of data using ListLogLogPlot.

```
x = {4.*^14, 4.*^15, 4.*^16};
y = {1170, 243, 50};
data = Partition[Riffle[x, y], 2];
```

However, when I go to plot this using ListLogLogPlot, the tick labels of the x-axes do not come out well:

```
ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{1*^14, 1*^17}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

I understand that tick mark labels can be edited using "Ticks". So I have tried creating custom tick labels that are rotated by 45 degrees. I would like there to be a label at 1E14, 1E15, 1E16, and 1E17:

```
 customTicks = Table[{i, Rotate[i, Pi/4]}, {i, {1.*^14, 1.*^15, 1.*^16, 1.*^17}}];
```

But when I update Ticks in ListLogLogPlot, the x-axis is just blank:

```
ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{1*^14, 1*^17}, Automatic}, Ticks -> {customTicks, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Does anyone know why the x-axis labels do now show up when rotated? Or know of a way to properly rotate the labels?

(I am a beginner with Mathematica. I have read through an earlier post on how to align rotated labels as well as the documentation on Ticks, FrameTicks, TicksStyle, however, I am unable to get the numbers to even display on the x-axis)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation; I have read through that post. I am just curious why the x-labels do not even show up in the above code

Comment: It's because it's a log scale, use something like Table[{Log[i], Rotate[i, Pi/4]}, ..], can't test I'm not near a computer right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version11.1，it works well.

In version10.4，exist this problem.

Try this(only run well in version10.4)：

```
ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{1*^14, 1*^17}, Automatic}] /. 
 Row[a___] :> Rotate[Row[a], 45 Degree]
```

[image]
maybe help (。・`ω´・)

Comment: I confirm that the problem exists in version 10.4.1 and is absent in versions 8.0.4, 11.0.1 and 11.1.1. Looks like it is a bug that was introduced in version 10 and fixed in version 11.